# Apply same style to multiple pictures in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pictures

I would like to select multiple images embedded in my e-mail and apply the same picture format to all of them or the picture format should be preselected when pasting the image from the clipboard.

If the only solution is scripting a point in the right direction would be appreciated (haven't created scripts in Outlook before).

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what?

Comment: @CharlieRB I've tried to select multiple pictures (using shift, ctrl, alt), searched through Outlook options, searched on google, searched on superuser.com. Did my answer helped you in any way?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I ask for the purpose of improving your question so those who are reading this will know what you've already tried and not duplicate your efforts as they attempt to help you.

Comment: All I've been able to find so far is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073463/vba-excel-2010-embedding-pictures-and-resizing) on StackExchange which might help you go in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've went with a Macro solution, although the script may not be correct (I've just read a little about VBA yesterday). I couldn't find a style constant, so I've added the properties that interested me (a shadow).

```vb
Public Sub AddShadow()
    Dim document As document
    Dim shape As InlineShape

    If Application.ActiveInspector Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not (TypeOf Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set document = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
    For Each shape In document.InlineShapes
        With shape
            If .Type = wdInlineShapePicture And .Width > 70 And .Height > 70 Then
                 With .Shadow
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
                    .Blur = 30
                    .Transparency = 0.29
                End With
            End If
        End With
        Next
    End
End Sub
```